# NLTK with flask import error

Tags: python, flask, nltk, importerror

My folder directory  is as such

```
/maindir
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  start
  /run.py
  /venv
    .. other directories for flask here bin,include..etc
  /app
    __init__.py
    main.py
    views.py
    /nbc
      /__init__.py
      naivebayesclassifier.py
```

The naivebayesclassifier.py module uses the nltk library as such

```
from nltk.probability import ELEProbDist, FreqDist
import nltk
from collections import defaultdict
from os import listdir  
from os.path import isfile, join
```

I'm having an issue where if I try to run the program directly from going into /app and running

```
python main.py
```

which further goes on to include nbc and use it, I have no problems.

However when I try to deploy this along with flask. I move one directory  out and run 
./start, which has the following

```
. venv/bin.activate
./run.py
```

and run.py has the following

```
#!venv/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

This has worked before I included the nltk library, however now it gives me the error saying

```
ImportError: No module named nltk.probability
```

I had installed nltk using

```
sudo pip install -U pyyaml nltk
```

but I feel I'm missing some installation somewhere to make it work while deploying.

Comment: What operating system are you using and which version of Python?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 and Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the activation of your virtualenv is causing the problem. Did you activate the virtualenv before running `sudo pip install -U pyyaml nltk`? If not, they were installed globally. Remember that by default, when you create a virtualenv environment, it will ignore all packages not installed directly into the environment itself (in other words, it will ignore the packages you installed globally using `apt-get install`). So, you have two options:

1. Install your dependencies into your virtualenv (by activating the virtualenv then doing `pip install nltk`).  If nltk depends on any development libraries, you will need to install those development libraries as well. Those can be installed using your package manager (`apt-get`).
2. Rebuild your virtualenv, this time using the [`--system-site-packages`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#the-system-site-packages-option) option. This will allow you to use packages installed outside of the virtualenv environment.

Comment: I had run sudo pip install -U pyyaml nltk within venv and it didn't seem to do anything. I instead just tried running pip install nltk and things seemed to work. thanks!

Comment: @Rahul: Ah, the `sudo` actually ran the pip command on a new shell, which means that the command ran outside of the virtualenv.